# erlang phylosophy: Should I let users deal with wrong input or not?

Tags: erlang

This is the case:

```
% print/1: Prints out the integers between 1 and N
print(0) ->   io:format("~w~n", [0]);
print(N) when is_integer(N) -> 
          io:format("~w~n", [N]),
          print(N - 1).
```

If the user inputs a non-integer, this happens:

```
11> effects:print('alfalfa').
** exception error: no function clause matching effects:print(alfalfa)
```

Is about phylosophy: Should I correct my program this way, in order to 'catch all' kinds of input?

```
% print/1: Prints out the integers between 1 and N
print(0) ->   io:format("~w~n", [0]);
print(N) when is_integer(N) -> 
          io:format("~w~n", [N]),
          print(N - 1).
% Last Line added:
print(_Other) -> false.
```

I'm new in erlang. Is there some convention for dealing with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Erlang you mostly would not catch such bad API usages. If no pattern matches the invocation, an [exception of class exit](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/errors.html) with a rather verbose message would be thrown (`{function_clause, CallStack}`).
Almost every standard library method throws. At the moment I fail to think of counterexamples.

Btw: You mostly would return `{error, Msg}`, not false, if there was some sort of error (mostly not usage error). In good cases `ok` or `{ok, Datum}` would be returned.

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful http://mazenharake.wordpress.com/2009/09/14/let-it-crash-the-right-way/